# How to combine multiple serverless.yml files to single serverless.yml file?

Tags: serverless-framework

I read this doc: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/google/guide/services/

```
users/
  serverless.yml # Contains 4 functions that do Users CRUD operations and the Users database
posts/
  serverless.yml # Contains 4 functions that do Posts CRUD operations and the Posts database
comments/
  serverless.yml # Contains 4 functions that do Comments CRUD operations and the Comments database
```

how can I combine these `serverless.yml` files to single `serverless.yml` file? Beside deploy each service, I can run `serverless deploy` once to deploy all services too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am defining functions in individual serverless.yml files and include file reference under functions in the main serverless.yml file and it works for me, I am also naming individual yml files as posts-sls.yml, users-sls.yml etc.

```
# foo-functions.yml
getFoo:
  handler: handler.foo
deleteFoo:
  handler: handler.foo

# serverless.yml
---
functions:
  - ${file(../foo-functions.yml)}
  - ${file(../bar-functions.yml)}
```

Referenced here:

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4218
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a plugin (like this one: https://github.com/economysizegeek/serverless-dir-config-plugin)

If you want more control, you can also do-it-yourself. For example, you could put the function specific configurations in each directory and then use a tool like `cat` to join them with a common one for the project (e.g. `cat serverless.common.yml users/serverless.yml posts/serverless.yml comments/serverless.yml > serverless.yml`). Although you may have to write something more complex if you want to merge together keys &c.